# Load combo values from ajax call using extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, combobox

I have a UI coded in ExtJS. I wish to have three things done when page loads:

1. Make an ajax call to server which retrieves a HashMap.
2. Create a combobox inside the main page Panel

   ```
   var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
   fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
   id: 'mycombo',
   queryMode: 'local',
   displayField: 'name',
   valueField: 'id',
   store: [],
   renderTo: Ext.getBody()
   });
   ```
3. Populate this combobox with the retrieved HashMap.

   ```
   combo.getStore().add([[i, m.get(i)]]);
   ```

Now when the page loads I need all three javascript codes to execute. Please advice as to how do I do that?

There is one more issue. The combo box creation code is inside the 'items' of the main page 'Panel' which I have coded in ExtJS. So how do i somehow call this creation code when the page is loaded? In short, I need to store the details of the combobox in a javascript 'var'

```
'var combo = Ext.create(....)`
```

which i can later use for populating the combobox. So how do I 'call' the code inside 'items' and assign it to 'var' when page loads, since after this I use the HashMap to populate this combobox using this 'var'.

Comment: `Ext.onReady(function () {
    // place your code here , in ajax success put the remaining two lies for constructing combo and changing it
});`

Comment: Thanx for the answer but the second issue remains. This combobox is there along with other UI elements on the page which I have coded in ExtJS. So the combobox creation code can only be there inside the 'items' section of the extjs code. And over there I cannot run javascript code unless its inside a function. How to get around this issue please advice

Answer (score 0):

That's a very normal feature that can be handled entirely by ExtJS. There is no need of manually adding records to the combo store one by one. You just need to define a store with an ajax proxy and attach it to the combobox component instead. That store would be configured to pull and parse its own data.

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/loh) is a simple example of how you can do that.

Comment: Will this work if the REST service which ajax calls is returning a HashMap ?

Comment: @aayush_v20 I'm guessing that by HashMap you are referring to a JSON object, which is what's being used in the example I gave you. If not a JSON, could you provide an example of the REST output?